# alias or function for emacs command?

Tags: alias, .profile

So I'm on my first day at my new job, and on the server we use, the default emacs is X-windows based.  I much prefer using it in the good old terminal, and I'd like to be able to make the command `emacs foo.txt` be read as  `emacs --no-window-system foo.txt`.

I tried to do this by adding the line `function emacs() { emacs --no-window-system "$@" ;}` to my `~/.profile`, and then ran `source ~/.profile`, but the system is unresponsive to `emacs foo.txt`.

Am I doing this wrong?  As an alternative, I would like to know if what I want to do is completely backwards, and it turns out that there is a far simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better as an alias.

Put this in your .profile or .bashrc

```
alias emacs='emacs -nw'
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not getting good results with this either.  I tried this in both .profile and .bashrc, ran `source .profile` or `source .bashrc` beforehand, and then ran `emacs foo.txt`, but both times nothing happens until I type Ctrl+D, at which point it returns to the prompt.

Comment: @FrankHarris What happens when you just `emacs -nw foo.txt`? I've never seen an Emacs build which was X-only, but I suppose such a thing is theoretically possible.

Comment: @AaronMiller, the problem has been resolved after I logged out and in again.  I was under the impression that `source .profile` would achieve the same thing, so not sure why it didn't work then!  It might've been a completely unrelated error, but the point is that it works now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AaronMiller I want to vote you up but I'm new and apparently need more reputation.  I'll try to remember to do so when I get it; you've been a big help.

Comment: @FrankHarris Thanks, and no worries! Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem with your original solution is that the call to `emacs` inside your `emacs` function is a recursive call to the `emacs` function.  You can call the `emacs` *program* instead of your `emacs` *function* by using the bash builtin `command`.

```
function emacs() { command emacs --no-window-system "$@" ;}
```

I have kind of the opposite desire: I want to automatically background emacs when I'm running under a window system.  I have the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    function emacs() { (command emacs "$@" &) }
fi
```